# Java IBM Lotus connection : NotesFactory create session fails with "UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am calling below method to connect to IBM notes:

```
session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess(Configs.NOTES_PASSWORD);
```

But my session fails with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at: lotus.domino.local.Session.NCreateSessionWithFullAccess(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at lotus.domino.local.Session.NCreateSessionWithFullAccess(Native Method)

I have Notes client Release 9.0.1 and I have added Notes folder to the Path. I'm running on Windows 10.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM provided Notes.jar only works with 32 bit jre. Mine was 64 bit. After changing the jre it works.